# Style a span with a specific width with CSS

Tags: styles, width, html

Is there a way to apply a style to a span when it reaches a specific width?

Like `span[width=100%]{ background-color: green }`.

I know I can do that on inputs, like `input[type=text]`, but I don't know how to do this on a span.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**1**-Get the current `width` of the element (JS) and apply a style when it is > than `X` value.

**2**-With [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), when the `width` is > than `X`, apply an specific style.

*If you want to specify a style sheet for handheld devices, or screen devices with a width greater than 20em, you can use this query:*

```
@media handheld and (min-width: 20em), screen and (min-width: 20em) { ... }
```

*The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).*